# Could anyone help me with a issue: Cannot Connect to Database Server(Mysql workbench, MAC OS)

Tags: mysql

I got this error when I tried to connect to local host, but it works fine last week. "Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I followed several ways in terminal: `sudo mysql -u root -p`
after i put my password, it says:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

no matter what i try, it always says access denied.
Would be appreciated if anyone could help!

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong password

Comment: When you installed MySQL did you get asked to enter a password for the root account? Did you enter one?

Comment: almost certainly not the issue but the `sudo` in `sudo mysql -u root -p` is probably not required and should be omitted

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the comments, it seems you are using the wrong password. This link explains how to reset the root password if ever you need it https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-windows-linux